# AngularJS Binding and &pound symbol

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm able to display pound successfully in the following example if I use the pound symbol directly in the JSON data. How can I tell angular that I want to display **Misko got £**?

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('oneTimeBidingExampleApp', []).
  controller('EventController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var counter = 0;
    var names = ['Igor got �', 'Misko got &pound;', 'Chirayu got £'];
    /*
     * expose the event object to the scope
     */
    $scope.clickMe = function(clickEvent) {
      $scope.name = names[counter % names.length];
      counter++;
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example28-production</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body ng-app="oneTimeBidingExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="EventController">
  <button ng-click="clickMe($event)">Click Me</button>
  <p id="one-time-binding-example">One time binding: {{::name}}</p>
  <p id="normal-binding-example">Normal binding: {{name}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ngSanitize as a dependency to your module. Also include the below script in your HTML.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

`angular.module('oneTimeBidingExampleApp', ['ngSanitize'])`

In your html use the ng-bind-html so that angular will display it as HTML instead of plain text

```
<p id="normal-binding-example">Normal binding: <span ng-bind-html="name"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular is escaping / sanitizing by default but you can use the ng-bind-html directive with sth like this to display html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="'Misko got &pound;'"></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-bind-html="name"></div>
```

more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize